# Magento product view page menu hide only specific product only

Tags: php, cms

[image]

how to remove components menu only in this page . where i find this page.

Comment: please specific magento version?

Comment: Magneto 1.9.2  or 2

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should edit the product in the admin panel directly and change the view there.